SDEs with measurable coefficients
I came across an SDE of the form
$$
d X_t = \mu_t(X_t) \, d t + \sigma_t(X_t) \, d W_t
$$
where for any $x$, $\mu_t(x)$ and $\sigma_t(x)$ are $W_t$-measurable processes, and both $\mu_t(.)$ and $\sigma_t(.)$ satisfy the usual Lipschitz and linear growth conditions almost surely (e.g., there exists $L \in \mathbb R_+$ such that $|{\mu_t(x) - \mu_t(y)}| \leq L |{x-y}|$ almost surely).
Would such an SDE be well-defined? Has this been studied somewhere?
Also, does anyone know of a reference that shows the convergence of standard numerical schemes when applied to an SDE with $W_t$-measurable coefficients?

Isn't this just the minimal condition on the underlying filtration? That it has to be finer than (incl. equal to) the filtration generated by the Brownian motion?

The references I've seen (like Kloeden and Platen) assume that the coefficients are L^2 measurable. Do you have a reference with such general conditions? Does it show convergence of numerical schemes? Thanks!

This is not a contradiction, more a complement. If you say $L^2$ then you have to also give the $\sigma$-algebra. But then it depends on what the arguments of the function really are. In stochastic processes it is common to have a silent argument into the probability space $\Omega$, so $\mu_t(X_t)$ could be in full form $\mu(t,X(t,\omega),\omega)$. The filtration refers to the third component, so one could demand $\mu_t\in L^2(\Bbb R^n\times\Omega)$ with the $\sigma$ algebra generated from the cross-products of $\cal L(\Bbb R^n)$ and $\cal F_t$.

Ah I see. I'll check what reference defines $L^2$ as. I am surprised that the $\Omega$ in the $L^2$ space would not be t-indexed.

The probability or event space is fixed. It is the $\sigma$ algebra above it that changes. For instance in the minimal algebra for Brownian motion, the event space is the space of all continuous paths, while $\cal F_t$ fixes the history up to time $t$. The Brownian motion itself is then $W_t(\omega)=\omega(t)$.

@LutzLehmann, the issue for me is that saying a or b are L^2 measurable can't possibly mean that they are $F_t$ measurable as well since there is no t dependence in the measurability statement. In any case, I check Kloeden and Platen book and confirmed that L^2 refers to Lebesgue measurability on $\mathbb R$. Are you aware of a reference that has the more general setup?
